# Call an Asp.net public method from a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, methods, html

I want to call an Asp.net public (static) method form a class but the page class is not accessible (I want EXACTLY this way not anything else):

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
...
   public static string MyFunc()
   {
   }
}
```

and in App_Code I have :

```
public class Class1
{
   public void AMethod(){
      var s=MyPage.MyFunc(); //<---Here MyPage is not accessible
   }
}
```

Comment: "I want EXACTLY this way not anything else" - why the rigidity?  It would be a _lot_ easier if you would put the static method in a different class.

Comment: you should maybe refference it?

Comment: Show us your namespaces

Comment: You can not make this call because this is a page, is called from asp.net it self to load the page... think a way around...

Comment: If MyPage itself isn't accessible, you don't have a reference to it. What do your namespaces and usings look like?

Comment: I don't have namespace for MyPage

Comment: Even when I add namespace for MyPage , both namespace and MyPage are inaccessible from class.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish here? Why the need to reference the certain page? There's a lot of ways to resolve this if you would further provide more info.

Comment: I am writing some code to convert ICallbackEventHandler ajax to SignalR connection. I mean instead of ajax(when Websocks can connect) I want to use SignalR. I don't want pages business code to be moved somewhere else.